# Eclipse EGIT not showing project I just cloned in package explorer?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I just cloned a repository in Eclipse. However, it is not showing up in the package explorer. How do I get it there? I see the branches and everything in repository view... but I cannot edit the contents.

Comment: Next time, try importing via File > Import > Projects from Git. This includes a step to import projects after cloning.

Comment: U can try go through this Tutorial [https://youtu.be/7Vy6sPkzwIg](https://youtu.be/7Vy6sPkzwIg)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right-click on the Working Directory in the Git Repositories view and Import the projects into the Eclipse workspace. They will not be copied. Clones can contain more than one project--wouldn't want to automatically import all of them (plus some of them might be one-off test projects buried in the tree somewhere).

Comment: It does not happen, even if I check "Import all existing Eclipse projects after clone finishes" while cloning. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: That requires there be .project files that were committed into the repository beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

In package explorer view -> Right click -> Team -> Share Project.
This should show the branch name in package explorer as well.

Comment: I think this answer is not related to the initial question since the author asked how to show them in the package explorer in general. However this is the answer to my problem (project available in package explorer with .git file included but not showing the repo information)

Answer (score 0):

If Git is located locally:

Right-Click in Project Explorer->"Import..." choose Git->"Projects from Git". Press Next and then "Existing local repository". Select the git repository, it will be imported in the Project Explorer

Answer (score 0):

To open the Package Explorer in Eclipse:

- Go to Windows -> Show View -> Package Explorer
- To add a repository to Package Explorer, right click on any existing repository/ package/projects  in the explorer
- Right click anywhere in Package Explorer area -> 'Import...' -> Git -> 'Projects from Git' -> 'Existing local repository' -> Choose the git repository -> Finish